# Go to line of file where number of lines minus "n"

Tags: command-line, terminal

Say I want to go to the 80th last line of my file `celery.log`, but I don't know how many lines it has.

The equivalent of the `tail` command but go to the 80th line from the end instead of the default.

How would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "go to"?

Comment: The equivilant of `tail` command but go to the 80th last line instead of the default.

Comment: like `tail -n80 celery.log` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '$-79p' | ed -s celery.log
```

This would run the `ed` script `$-79p` on the file called `celery.log`, which would display the line that is 79 lines up from the last line of the file.

In a shell that understands here-strings:

```
ed -s celery.log <<<'$-79p'
```

If the file has less than 80 lines, `ed` will return an error (the character `?` on its standard error stream) and produce no output on the standard output stream.

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -n 80 celery.log | head -n 1
```

This will show the first of the last 80 lines (if the file has fewer than 80 lines, it will show the first line of the file).

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do this:

```
tac celery.log | sed -n '80p'
```